# Count months between two timestamp on postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I want to count the number of months between two dates.

Doing :

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2012-06-13 10:38:40' - TIMESTAMP '2011-04-30 14:38:40';
```

Returns : 
    0 years 0 mons 409 days 20 hours 0 mins 0.00 secs

and so:

```
SELECT extract(month from TIMESTAMP '2012-06-13 10:38:40' - TIMESTAMP '2011-04-30 14:38:40');
```

returns 0.

Answer (score 69):

`age` function returns interval:

```
age(timestamp1, timestamp2)
```

Then we try to extract year and month out of the interval and add them accordingly:

```
select extract(year from age(timestamp1, timestamp2)) * 12 +
extract(month from age(timestamp1, timestamp2))
```

Comment: Good solution thanks, I also added this to add 1 month for the remaining days if there were more than 20 in the difference: + case when extract(days from age(timestamp1, timestamp2)) > 20 then 1 else 0 end

Answer (score 23):

Please note that the most voted answer by [@ram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2754166/ram-sharma) and [@angelin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/412591/angelin-nadar) is not accurate when you are trying to get calendar month difference using.

```sql
select extract(year from age(timestamp1, timestamp2))*12 + extract(month from age(timestamp1, timestamp2))
```

for example, if you try to do:

```
select extract(year from age('2018-02-02'::date, '2018-03-01'::date))*12 + extract(month from age('2018-02-02'::date , '2018-03-01'::date))
```

**the result will be 0** but in terms of months between March from February should be 1 no matter the days between dates.

so the formula should be like the following saying that we start with timestamp1 and timestamp2:

((year2 - year1)*12) - month1 + month2 = calendar months between two timestamps

in pg that would be translated to:

```
select ((extract('years' from '2018-03-01 00:00:00'::timestamp)::int -  extract('years' from '2018-02-02 00:00:00'::timestamp)::int) * 12) 
    - extract('month' from '2018-02-02 00:00:00'::timestamp)::int + extract('month' from '2018-03-01 00:00:00'::timestamp)::int;
```

you can create a function like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION months_between (t_start timestamp, t_end timestamp)
RETURNS integer
AS $$
select ((extract('years' from $2)::int -  extract('years' from $1)::int) * 12) 
    - extract('month' from $1)::int + extract('month' from $2)::int
$$
LANGUAGE SQL
IMMUTABLE
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT;
```

Answer (score 20):

The `age` function give a justified interval to work with:

```
SELECT age(TIMESTAMP '2012-06-13 10:38:40', TIMESTAMP '2011-04-30 14:38:40');
```

returns `1 year 1 mon 12 days 20:00:00`, and with that you can easily use `EXTRACT` to count the number of months:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM age) * 12 + EXTRACT(MONTH FROM age) AS months_between
FROM age(TIMESTAMP '2012-06-13 10:38:40', TIMESTAMP '2011-04-30 14:38:40') AS t(age);
```

Comment: Clever to add years and months :)

Answer (score 8):

If you will do this multiple times, you could define the following [function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createfunction.html):

```
CREATE FUNCTION months_between (t_start timestamp, t_end timestamp)
    RETURNS integer
    AS $$
        SELECT
            (
                12 * extract('years' from a.i) + extract('months' from a.i)
            )::integer
        from (
            values (justify_interval($2 - $1))
        ) as a (i)
    $$
    LANGUAGE SQL
    IMMUTABLE
    RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT;
```

so that you can then just

```
SELECT months_between('2015-01-01', now());
```

Comment: You might need to cast `now()` to timestamp. So example would be `select months_between('2015-01-01', now()::timestamp);`

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT date_part ('year', f) * 12
      + date_part ('month', f)
FROM age ('2015-06-12', '2014-12-01') f
```

Result: 6 Months

Answer (score 2):

Gives the differenece of months of two dates

```
   SELECT ((extract( year FROM TIMESTAMP '2012-06-13 10:38:40' ) - extract( year FROM TIMESTAMP '2011-04-30 14:38:40' )) *12) + extract(MONTH FROM TIMESTAMP '2012-06-13 10:38:40' ) - extract(MONTH FROM TIMESTAMP '2011-04-30 14:38:40' );
```

The Result : 14

Have to extract months seperately for both the dates and then the difference of both the results

Comment: I think we are on the way but it is still buggy. The result with your proposition is 14 and the good response is 13.

Comment: select EXTRACT(year FROM age(TIMESTAMP '2012-06-13 10:38:40',TIMESTAMP '2011-04-30 14:38:40'))*12 + EXTRACT(month FROM age(TIMESTAMP '2012-06-13 10:38:40',TIMESTAMP '2011-04-30 14:38:40'));

Comment: I have edited your answer with the implemented solution. It should be visible after the peer review.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a PostgreSQL function with the exact same behavior as the Oracle MONTHS_BETWEEN function.
It has been tested on a wide range of years (including leap ones) and more than 700k combinations of dates (including end of every months).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION months_between
(   DATE,
    DATE
)
RETURNS float
AS
$$
    SELECT
            (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM $1) - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM $2)) * 12
        +   EXTRACT(MONTH FROM $1) - EXTRACT(MONTH FROM $2)
        +   CASE
                WHEN    EXTRACT(DAY FROM $2) = EXTRACT(DAY FROM LAST_DAY($2))
                    AND EXTRACT(DAY FROM $1) = EXTRACT(DAY FROM LAST_DAY($1))
                THEN
                    0
                ELSE
                    (EXTRACT(DAY FROM $1) - EXTRACT(DAY FROM $2)) / 31
            END
    ;
$$
LANGUAGE SQL
IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

This function requires a LAST_DAY function (behaving the same as Oracle's one) :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION last_day
(   DATE
)
RETURNS DATE
AS
$$
    SELECT
        (DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', $1) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH' - INTERVAL '1 DAY')::date
    ;
$$
LANGUAGE SQL
IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem once upon a time and wrote this ... it's quite ugly:

```
postgres=>  SELECT floor((extract(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP '2012-06-13 10:38:40' ) - extract(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP '2005-04-30 14:38:40' ))/30.43/24/3600);
 floor 
-------
    85
(1 row)
```

In this solution "one month" is defined to be 30.43 days long, so it may give some unexpected results over shorter timespans.

Comment: It's working but it's very weird. The other problem I see is the fact that you consider that a month is 30 days. From the 3th of february to the 4th of march there is one month. Your select will returns 0. And from the 3st of january to the 2nd of february there is not a month. Your select will returns one.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it's only approximately correct (but it was good enough for me).  (edited it to make it more clear).

Comment: its approximate because of the use of `30` since months can be longer or shorter - the greater the distance between the timestamps the more this becomes an issue - similar timestamps rounding will suffice.

Comment: I have replaced 30 with 30.43 so it will be more correct on long timespans :-)

Answer (score 1):

Extract by year and months will floor on months:

```
select extract(year from age('2016-11-30'::timestamp, '2015-10-15'::timestamp)); --> 1
select extract(month from age('2016-11-30'::timestamp, '2015-10-15'::timestamp)); --> 1
--> Total 13 months
```

This approach maintains fractions of months (thanks to tobixen for the divisor)

```
select round(('2016-11-30'::date - '2015-10-15'::date)::numeric /30.43, 1); --> 13.5 months
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
SELECT extract (MONTH FROM age('2014-03-03 00:00:00'::timestamp, 
'2013-02-03 00:00:00'::timestamp)) + 12 * extract (YEAR FROM age('2014-03-03   
00:00:00'::timestamp, '2013-02-03 00:00:00'::timestamp)) as age_in_month;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT floor(extract(days from TIMESTAMP '2012-06-13 10:38:40' - TIMESTAMP
'2011-04-30 14:38:40')/30.43)::integer as months;
```

Gives an approximate value but avoids duplication of timestamps. This uses hint from [tobixen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11013023/19501) to divide by 30.43 in place of 30 to be less incorrect for long timespans while computing months.

Answer (score 0):

I made a function like this:

```
/* similar to ORACLE's MONTHS_BETWEEN */
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ORACLE_MONTHS_BETWEEN(date_from DATE, date_to DATE)
RETURNS REAL LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
DECLARE age INTERVAL;
declare rtn real;
BEGIN
    age := age(date_from, date_to);
    rtn := date_part('year', age) * 12 + date_part('month', age) + date_part('day', age)/31::real;
    return rtn;
END;
$$;
```

Oracle Example)

```
SELECT MONTHS_BETWEEN
(TO_DATE('2015-02-02','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2014-12-01','YYYY-MM-DD') ) 
"Months" FROM DUAL;
--result is: 2.03225806451612903225806451612903225806
```

My PostgreSQL function example)

```
select ORACLE_MONTHS_BETWEEN('2015-02-02'::date, '2014-12-01'::date) Months;
-- result is: 2.032258
```

From the result you can use CEIL()/FLOOR() for rounding.

```
select ceil(2.032258)  --3
select floor(2.032258) --2
```

Answer (score -2):

Try;

```
select extract(month from  age('2012-06-13 10:38:40'::timestamp, '2011-04-30 14:38:40'::timestamp)) as my_months;
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. It returns `1`, because `extract` only takes into account the month, but not how many months you have because of the years involved in the difference.