# use the calculation from CASE in the result in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_a AS 
 SELECT distinct p.partid, case when 
                (SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM age) * 12 + EXTRACT(MONTH FROM age) 
                FROM age(NOW(), LEAST(pp.createdate)) AS t(age)) AS months_between

                <24 then months_between::integer else 24  end as timeframe
   FROM ....
  WHERE ....;
```

This view takes `createdate` (time stamp of the oldest recorded creation date per `partid`) and calculates the months passed since this date to `NOW()`  same as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012629/count-months-between-two-timestamp-on-postgresql)
if the result is smaller than 24 (months) I want this result otherwise I want 24.

This currently not working it doesn't accept the `AS months_between` in the middle of the case.

**How can I do that?**

**EDIT :**

For example this query works:

```
 SELECT distinct p.partid, case when 
                (SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM age) * 12 + EXTRACT(MONTH FROM age) 
                FROM age(NOW(), LEAST(pp.createdate)) AS t(age)) 
                <24 then 5 else 24  end as timeframe
   FROM ....
  WHERE ....;
```

However it will return 5 or 24 and it's not what I want. I want it to return the value calculated in the CASE.

To simplify the question basically the form is:

```
case when calculated_value < 24 then calculated_value  else 24 end;
```

I want to be able to return the calculated_value  in the case.

Comment: Can't you use LEAST here? see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-conditional.html#AEN12704

Comment: @RC. LEAST is not the issue. See the edit.

Comment: Then just copy paste that calculation to your THEN... ELSE

Comment: @PhamX.Bach I am aware of that however the table is huge... it takes forever I'm trying to avoid it. I'm sure there is a way not to calculate same value twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to move *months_between calculation* to the [common table expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html) (WITH query), something like this:

```
WITH timeframe_table AS (
    SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM age) * 12 + EXTRACT(MONTH FROM age) 
    FROM age(NOW(), LEAST(pp.createdate)) AS months_between 
) SELECT
    CASE when months_between< 24 then months_between else 24 as timeframe
        FROM ..., timeframe_table
        WHERE...
```

You may need to add some id field to timeframe_table to have some join condition with your table.

Comment: Could you provide more information about your query and "where" conditions?

Comment: You could still add `DISTINCT`, you could move your `WHERE` conditions inside the WITH clause. However, I need more details to help in solving the issue you've stuck with.