# How to get the full calendar months between two dates in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, datediff, date-arithmetic

I have two dates, e.g. `'2022-01-03'` and `'2022-03-04'`, is there any neat way to calculate ONLY the completed full calendar months between these dates?

Some examples with their requested outputs:

```
'2022-01-03' and '2022-03-04'
```

full calendar months = 1 since only February was a full calendar month between this timespan.

```
'2022-01-01' and '2022-05-30'
```

full calendar months = 4 since May has 31 days total.

```
'2022-01-31' and '2022-05-31'
```

full calendar months = 3 since the month of May is not completed.

I tried subtracting the dates but it gives me the days difference between these dates.
I also tried the function AGE() but it is based also in the days difference, since it is using days to calculate years months etc.

Comment: Maybe this can help you. I guess the first answer is what you need. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012629/count-months-between-two-timestamp-on-postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a full range of days between the two dates as complete months, and then `left join` all the days only between the original dates. This way, you can check if any months are missing days.  The query below is formatted as a function for ease of use:

```sql
create function calendar_months(a timestamp, b timestamp) 
returns int as
$$
declare
 total int;
begin
  select sum(case when t1.rec = t1.total then 1 else 0 end) into total 
  from (select extract(year from t), extract(month from t), 
    sum(case when t1 is not null then 1 else 0 end) rec, count(*) total 
    from generate_series(date_trunc('month', a), date_trunc('month', b) + interval '1 month' - interval '1 day', interval '1 day') t 
    left join generate_series(a, b - interval '1 day', interval '1 day') t1 on t = t1 
    group by extract(year from t), extract(month from t)) t1;
  return total;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_ePjgGj-).

Comment: Thanks, @Ajax1234 !! This one solved my case!!

Answer (score 2):

First adjust the two dates to be the first day of the first full month and the last day of the last full month plus one day (`t` CTE) and then calculate the age between the two adjusted dates. Here is an illustration using `sample_data` CTE.

```sql
with sample_data(d1, d2) as (values
('2022-01-03'::date,'2022-03-04'::date),('2022-01-01','2022-05-30'),('2022-01-31','2022-05-31')),

t as
( 
 select 
  case when d1 = date_trunc('month', d1) 
       then d1 
       else date_trunc('month', d1) + interval '1 month' end::date m1,
  case when d2 = date_trunc('month', d2) + interval '1 month - 1 day' 
       then d2 + interval '1 day'
       else date_trunc('month', d2) end::date m2
 from sample_data
) 
select m1, m2, age(m2, m1) from t;
```

| m1 | m2 | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-01 | 2022-03-01 | 1 mon |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022-05-01 | 4 mons |
| 2022-02-01 | 2022-06-01 | 4 mons |